# How to merge individual date fields like order day, order month and order year to create a order date?

Tags: tableau-api

Ex. Order Day "1"
Order Month "Jan"
Order Year "2020"

Required Date: 1 JAN 2020

Answer (score 1):

If each of these are separate fields, I would build a text version of the date and wrap it in the `DATE()` function, but there are probably a dozen ways to do it differently.

DATE( [OrderYear] + "-" + [OrderMonth] + "-" + [OrderDay] )

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your data is

[image]

- Step-1:  Convert all three fields to string type, if not so.
- Step-2: create a calculated field say `order date full` with the following calculation

```
DATE(DATEPARSE("dd:MMM:yyyy", [order date] + ':' + [order month] + ':' + [order year]))
```

get results like this

[image]